# angular $scope.variable is not updating using a ng-model directive on input

Tags: angularjs, angular-ngmodel

I am working on an angular app with a view where the user has an input where he can set his phone number.

```
 <div class="modal">
      <ion-header-bar  class="actu_header">
      <h1 class="title">Nouvelles Infos</h1>
      <div class="button button-clear" style="width:50px" ng-click="cancel()"><span class="icon ion-chevron-down"></span></div>
    </ion-header-bar>
    <ion-content  class="padding_header modalPhone">
    <h4> Entrez votre numéro de téléphone pour confirmer votre compte</h4>
    <label class="item item-input">
      <span class="input-label"><i class="ion-ios-telephone"></i> </span>
      <input type="tel" ng-model="telephone" placeholder="Entrez votre numero de mobile"/>
    </label>
    <p class="err_container" ng-if="err">{{err}}</p>
    <button ng-click="sendPhoneNumber()" class="button homepage_button icon-right ">
      Valider
  </button>
  </ion-content>
</div>
```

when the user clicks on the button. It is supposed to send the telephone data to the server. This is the relevant controller from which the preceding modal depends:

```
    .controller('RegisterCtrl', function($scope, $http, $location, $localStorage,$ionicLoading, $ionicHistory, mySock, user,$cordovaNetwork, $ionicModal){
  $ionicHistory.clearCache();
  $ionicHistory.clearHistory();
  $scope.err = "";
  $scope.user={};
  // $scope.telephone = "";

  $scope.launchModal = function(){
    $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('templates/phoneConfirmation.html', {
      scope: $scope,
      animation: 'slide-in-up'
    }).then(function(modal) {
      $scope.modal2 = modal;
      $scope.modal2.show();
    });
  }

  $scope.cancel = function(){
    $scope.goBack(-1);
    $scope.modal2.hide();
  }

  // $scope.telephone = "";

  $scope.sendPhoneNumber = function(){
    console.log($scope.telephone);
    $http.post(serverAddress+'/user/sendConfirmationSms', {telephone: $scope.telephone}).success(function(data){})
  }
  $scope.launchReq = function(){
    if($scope.err)
      delete $scope.err;
    if(window.device && $cordovaNetwork.isOffline()){
      error_reporter.show({texte: "Connectez vous d'abord à internet!"});
    }
    else{
      $ionicLoading.show({
        content: 'Loading Data',
        animation: 'fade-out',
        showBackdrop: false,
        hideOnStateChange: true
      });
      $http.post(serverAddress+'/user/create',$scope.user).success(function(data){
       $localStorage.set('token',data[0].token);
       $localStorage.setObject('user',data[0]);
       $localStorage.setObject('friends',[]);
       user.getCoord();
       mySock.req(serverAddress+'/connexion/setSocket',{id: data[0].id}); //Link socket_id with the user.id
       $location.path('/user/profil');
     }).error(function(err){
      $ionicLoading.hide();
      $scope.err = "Erreur veuillez vérifier que tous les champs sont remplis et que l'adresse mail n'est pas déjà utilisée.";
    });
   }
 }
})
```

Whatever I type in the input field the value of $scope.telephone that prints to the console is always an empty string.
Thus the value of telephone is not actually sent to the server even though I specified ng-model="telephone" on the input tag.

---update---

The problematic peace of html was actually a modal triggered by clicking on an element with the function launchModal in the registerCtrl.
By unlinking my modal from the RegisterCtrl and linking it to a new controller it finally worked :

```
<div class="modal" ng-controller ="PhoneCtrl">
        <ion-header-bar  class="actu_header">
      <h1 class="title">Nouvelles Infos</h1>
      <div class="button button-clear" style="width:50px" ng-click="cancel()"><span class="icon ion-chevron-down"></span></div>
    </ion-header-bar>
     <ion-content  class="padding_header modalPhone">
    <h4> Entrez votre numéro de téléphone pour confirmer votre compte</h4>
    <label class="item item-input">
      <span class="input-label"><i class="ion-ios-telephone"></i> </span>
      <input type="tel" ng-model="$parent.telephone" placeholder="Entrez votre numero de mobile"/>
    </label>
    <p class="err_container" ng-if="err">{{err}}</p>
    <button ng-click="sendPhoneNumber()" class="button homepage_button icon-right ">
      Valider
  </button>
  </ion-content>
</div>
```

and this is the new controller

```
.controller('PhoneCtrl', function($scope, $http, $location, $localStorage,$ionicLoading, $ionicHistory, mySock, user,$cordovaNetwork, $ionicModal){ 

  $scope.cancel = function(){
    $scope.goBack(-1);
    $scope.modal2.hide();
  }

  $scope.sendPhoneNumber = function(){
    alert($scope.telephone)
    console.log($scope.telephone);
    $http.post(serverAddress+'/user/sendConfirmationSms', {telephone: $scope.telephone}).success(function(data){})
  }
 })
```

But I still dont understand why it wasnt working in the original controller.. if someone has an idea ?

Comment: Are you sure it is the binding which isn't working and not the server call? if you add `console.log($scope.telephone)` above `$http.post`, does the telephone number get logged to the console as you expect?

Comment: I believe you are not binding your div to controller.

Comment: @Rhumborl no when I try to ```console.log($scope.telephone```the only thing I get is an empty string no matter what

Comment: Please post your HTML and JS file completely.  I am getting proper value on console. Try with my answer again.

Comment: @PratapA.K, just did that

Comment: @DavidGeismar : See my updated answer. It will solve your problem. Problem was with your <ion-content></ion-content> binding to Angular $scope. So two way binding was not happening.

Comment: @DavidGeismar  I have updated my answer, My index.html contains all the code

Comment: @PratapA.K I got it to work finally by separating the modal logic in a new controller (see my updated post) but I still dont know why it wasnt working keeping everything in a single controller, if you have an idea

Comment: Not sure!! Take a look at this https://jsfiddle.net/o3574h8h/1/ 
It's still working for me with same controller. Any how, you got it working, that's great.

If my answer satisfies you/solves your problem, you can mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is specific with ion-content because of the way this directive is defined in the Ionic source code. It specifically creates it's own child scope.

I am able to get around the problem by binding my inputs to 
$parent.telephone

**change this**

```
ng-model="telephone"
```

**To this**

```
ng-model="$parent.telephone"
```

**So**

```
<ion-content  class="padding_header modalPhone">
    <h4> Entrez votre numéro de téléphone pour confirmer votre compte</h4>
    <label class="item item-input">
      <span class="input-label"><i class="ion-ios-telephone"></i> </span>
      <input type="tel" ng-model="$parent.telephone" placeholder="Entrez votre numero de mobile"/>
    </label>
    <p class="err_container" ng-if="err">{{err}}</p>
    <button ng-click="sendPhoneNumber()" class="button homepage_button icon-right ">
      Valider
  </button>
  </ion-content>
```

More details you can find here

[problem-with-ion-content-and-scope-vars-inside-function](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/problem-with-ion-content-and-scope-vars-inside-function/1811/7)

as per your request, take a look below

**my Index.html with controller**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="routerApp">
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
<script src="//rawgithub.com/g00fy-/angular-datepicker/1.0.3/dist/index.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.15/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
<script>

var routerApp = angular.module('routerApp', ['ui.router', 'ionic', 'ngCordova']);

routerApp.controller('RegisterCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$location', '$ionicLoading', '$ionicHistory','$cordovaNetwork', '$ionicModal', 
                                      function($scope, $http, $location, $ionicLoading, $ionicHistory,$cordovaNetwork, $ionicModal){
    $scope.telephone = "";

      $scope.sendPhoneNumber = function(){
          alert("--"+$scope.telephone);
        console.log($scope.telephone);
        /* $http.post(serverAddress+'/user/sendConfirmationSms', {telephone: $scope.telephone}).success(function(data){}) */
      }

    }]);

</script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="RegisterCtrl">
    <div class="modal">
        <ion-header-bar  class="actu_header">
      <h1 class="title">Nouvelles Infos</h1>
      <div class="button button-clear" style="width:50px" ng-click="cancel()"><span class="icon ion-chevron-down"></span></div>
    </ion-header-bar> 
     <ion-content  class="padding_header modalPhone">
    <h4> Entrez votre numéro de téléphone pour confirmer votre compte</h4> 
    <label class="item item-input">
      <span class="input-label"><i class="ion-ios-telephone"></i> </span>
      <input type="tel" ng-model="$parent.telephone" placeholder="Entrez votre numero de mobile"/>
    </label>
    <p class="err_container" ng-if="err">{{err}}</p>
    <button ng-click="sendPhoneNumber()" class="button homepage_button icon-right ">
      Valider
  </button>
  </ion-content> 
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ionic/1.2.4/js/ionic.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ng-cordova/0.1.23-alpha/ng-cordova.min.js"></script>
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

make sure you will download and reference cordova.js in your html file.

Comment: when I console.log($scope.telephone) I always get an empty string no matter what I have in my input tag

Comment: Above code is working for me!! I am getting entered value on console.

Comment: Hey Pratap, thanks for your answer but I still cant update console.log my telephone value (It doesnt know the $parent service...) Can you show me how you update the code on controller side ?

Comment: still getting blank space when I try to console.log telephone. But when I display {{telephone}} directly in the view, it is working

Comment: Did you try to execute my code(index.html)? I am getting entered value on console. I am not facing any issue.
If still needed help, create a jsfiddle/Plunker and provide the link.

Answer (score 0):

Is it the total code you are using? If yes, then you missed 'config' variable in $http.post() call.

config should include the headers which you haven't included in the above code!

If you have included it in your code, please share the actual files.

Answer (score 0):

if you are sure about your request json like this ,

```
{
telephone:$scope.telephone
}
```

try followings:

1) use console.log($scope.telephone) above the service to check if its correct value.

2) try to edit your json like this `

```
$http.post(serverAddress+'/user/sendConfirmationSms', 
{
"telephone": $scope.telephone
})
.success(function(data){})
```

3) check your service url and port numbers (this is important general mistake)